# Unable to click Next button on gmail login page using selenium

Tags: html, class, selenium, xpath

I am new in automation testing and learning selenium. I was coding for Selenium program for Gmail Login. I am able to hit url and enter username but there is button called "Next" on same page which I am unable to click to go further .I tried clicking same using "xpath".
Below is the html code for that button when I inspected element using FireBug.

```
<span class="RveJvd" snByac">Next</span>
```

My code:

```
WebElement we = driver.findElement(By.id("identifierId")); we.sendKeys("emailid"); 
driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]‌​/div[2]/form/div[2]/‌​div/div[2]/div[1]/di‌​v/content/span]")).c‌​lick();
```

Comment: Where is your code?

Comment: it's easy but let us know what you tried? what kind of `XPath` you have used and what exception you got?

Comment: WebElement we = driver.findElement(By.id("identifierId"));
 we.sendKeys("emailid");
 driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/form/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/content/span]")).click();

Comment: I hope this much code is enough. Unable to post entire code due character limitation in comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following.

```
WebElement we = driver.findElement(By.id("identifierId"));
we.sendKeys("emailid");
driver.findElement(By.id("identifierNext")).c‌​lick();
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked. How did you identify the "identifierNext"? And there is one more Next button after entering password. What to use there? Thankz.

Comment: driver.findElement(By.id("passwordNext")).click() after entering password. checked the parent of the element and it has id. please accept my answer.

Comment: Okay! Thank u for so much.

Answer (score 0):

after entering id, and for that next  use

```
driver.findElement(By.id("identifierNext")).c‌​lick();
```

after giving password and then for that next use

```
driver.findElement(By.id("passwordNext")).c‌​lick();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
WebElement we = driver.findElement(By.id("identifierId"));

 we.sendKeys("emailid"); 

 driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("span[class='RveJvd']")).click();
```